$I \sigma (I)$ is a principal ideal in a quadratic number ring
I started learning about number theory and I can't understand this exercise that was left in lecturer's notes.
Exercise: Let $K$ be a quadratic number field and $\sigma: K \to K$ a nontrivial $\mathbb{Q}$-automorphism. Show that for any ideal $I \lhd \mathcal{O}_K$ (the latter denotes the ring of all algebraic integers in $K$), the ideal $I \sigma(I)$ is principal.
This was asked here before in greater generality, but I genuinely can't comprehend any of the answers. At this point in the notes, we have covered factorization of ideals in Dedekind domains. How would someone who doesn't have a clue about ideal norms prove this?

It’s enough to show it for all prime ideals, no? For inert primes it’s tautological, otherwise it’s just the decomposition of $p\mathcal{O}_K$, no?

Sure, it's enough to do it for prime ideals but I don't know how to do it for prime ideals. What is an inert prime? And what is $p$ in $p \mathcal{O}_K$?

This can be proved without using ideal norms or reduction to the case of prime ideals: see Theorem 5.4 here, whose proof is based on Theorem 5.6 and its generalization Theorem 5.9. The key point in these theorems is that they show $I\sigma(I)$ is an ideal generated by ordinary integers, and the proofs relies in an essential way on working with ideals in the full ring of algebraic integers rather than in some proper subring (e.g., $\mathbf Z[3i]$ is bad but $\mathbf Z[i]$ is good).

Thanks for this. I'll accept your answer, but the proof seems long and elaborate. Do you know how to prove this by reducing to the case of prime ideals?

Show every (nonzero) prime ideal is a factor of $p\mathcal O_K$ for some prime number $p$ and then use a description of the generators of the prime ideal factors of $p\mathcal O_K$  (this is in many algebraic number theory books) to show when $P$ is a prime ideal factor of $p\mathcal O_K$ that either $p\mathcal O_K = P$, in which case $P\sigma(P) = p^2\mathcal O_K$, or $p\mathcal O_K = P\sigma(P)$.  This is exactly what the comment above by Aphelli says. You should talk to your lecturer to get more information on what was intended in the exercise.

Awesome. Thank you so much.
